# Why is the OpenMP reduction clause needed to make reductions concurrent?

Tags: c, openmp, reduction

The OpenMP 'parallel' construct and 'SIMD' construct (new in revision 4.0) define the [reduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88b1k8y5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) clause which tells the compiler which variable the reduction is performed on and what is the reduction operator.
But why does the compiler need the programmer to tell it this information? GCC, for example, has the capability of identifying reductions without getting any help from the programmer (see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html#slp-reduc-1) and [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html#slp-reduc-2)).
Are there any examples of loops that cannot be made concurrent without specifying the reduction clause?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand you, but you seem to be confusing vectorization and threading.

Comment: I understand the difference between the two. What do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Reductions are a simple mechanism to improve the performance of parallel applications by removing synchronisation points and at the price of relaxed consistence of memory view. The need to explicitly have a reduction clause should be immediately apparent from the following example:

Imagine that you have a code that does a search over an unordered collection of `NUM_ITEMS` items and the goal is to find all items that match given criteria and to collect them in an array `matches` as well as to compute the sum of some property of these items. It doesn't matter in what order the items are found. The serial code could be something like this:

```
int num_matches = 0;
int prop_sum = 0;

for (i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
{
   if (criteria(item[i]))
   {
      match[num_matches] = item[i];
      num_matches++;
      prop_sum += item[i]->some_property;
   }
}
```

Both `num_matches` and `prop_sum` are variables, whose values are accumulated as the loop goes. But both variables have completely different semantics. While it is possible that `prop_sum` can be computed as a sum of partial sums, `num_matches` cannot because of its use as an index in the output array. `prop_sum` is a typical candidate for reduction while `num_matches` cannot only be reduced, but also one has to utilise an explicit synchronisation construct in order to prevent data races and different threads overwriting the same element of `match`:

```
int num_matches = 0;
int prop_sum = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:prop_sum)
for (i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
{
   if (criteria(item[i]))
   {
      #pragma omp critical(update_matches)
      {
          match[num_matches] = item[i];
          num_matches++;
      }
      prop_sum += item[i]->some_property;
   }
}
```

Although you might argue that the compiler might be smart enough to notice the way `num_matches` is used and automatically generate atomic increments, the goal of OpenMP is to be *portable* among platforms and compiler vendors. That means that if you write an OpenMP program that conforms to the standard and compiles and works correctly with one compiler, then it should compile and work correctly with other compilers too. The standard is written by many different vendors and not everyone of them has this super smart data dependency discovery mechanism. Besides it becomes very hard to have reliable detection when data, external to the compilation unit, is involved.

`reduction` is not a necessity - it is merely a convenience. You can implement your own reduction e.g. using atomic increments and this might be optimal for your platform, but it might be very far from optimal on other platforms that do not provide efficient atomic increments. On the other side, it is expected that each compiler will generate code that implements the `reduction` clause in the best possible way for the given target platform.

Comment: Sorry, but i do not follow your example. What does the reduction used for computing prop_sum have to do with the computation of match and num_matches? They merely are computed in the same loop/control-flow path. What am i missing here?

Comment: You are missing that to the compiler both look the same - something is added to a variable at each iteration. The difference is that the intermediate values of `prop_sum` are not significant and the OpenMP compiler is free to use private variables that are reduced at the end of the parallel region in order to obtain the final value. On the other side the intermediate values of `num_matches` are significant and therefore no reduction can be applied to it. The difference is subtle and it could be hard for the compiler to tell one from the other, therefore the explicit `reduction` clause.

Comment: For another example of where a compiler is unlikely to automatically figure out the right reduction operator, see the last listing in http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/weird-openmp-reduction .  Even many human programmers would have a tough time figuring out that "+" is the right reduction operation for the two variables being manipulated with &=, |=, <<=, and ^=.

Comment: @ArchD.Robison that was convincing example

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer to the original question, which was talking about #pragma omp simd, not #pragma omp parallel for.